How to enable Intellisense for Bamboo Specs Java in IntelliJ
Is it possible to have Intellisense support for Bamboo Specs Java in Jetbrains IntelliJ?
Here's what I have done so far.
I have JDK 22 and Maven installed.
I have a Bamboo Specs file from my current project
Tested project with mvn test, which seems to download all dependencies provided in pom.xml file.
The test is green.
But intellisense do not work. Does anyone know how to enable it?

Hello, are you talking about https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs-docs/6.5.0/specs-java.html#project? (But intellisense do not work) Does it mean that the auto-completion didn't work? Any screenshots are welcome.

Answered in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79059344/13896959

I've already found a solution. I had to open the project where pom.xml file is on the main level of the repository. Proviously I was opening repo few levels higher and it was the main reason of not working intellisense.
